# This div seems stuck in the navigation area...?

Tags: html, css, iframe

The form at the top of this page: http://kgshowroom.com/test/builder-test.html is supposed to go under title "Testing the Builder Thing" but no matter where I put the "header" "div" or "article" tags around the iframe for the form, it doesn't budge. I tried looking into the css for it, but I must be missing something. And I know it's gotta be a simple something!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the CSS value `position: absolute;` set on the form's parent iframe. That removes it from the normal document flow, which prevents it from affecting the positions of any sibling elements (i.e. it overlaps them instead of pushing them out of the way). It also makes the browser calculate the iframe's position relative to its containing block rather than its sibling elements (though only if used in conjunction with the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, or `left` properties). That, together with the CSS value, `top: 0;`, is why the iframe is stuck at the top of the page.

Changing the position value to `relative` will fix the problem. Deleting the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties might also work, but I'd try the relative positioning first. Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for more info on CSS positioning.

Comment: So, I didn't create this iFrame, it was a code from a cabinet company that they give to their clients to allow them to log in, and it's just a generic code that they give out, I just dropped it into my site's code. This is the code I have for it (see next comment; this one isn't allowing me to paste it all in here)

Comment: <!-- Begin Login Box -->
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <div style="border:2px solid #cccccc;border-radius:4px;margin:0 auto;max-width:400px;">
                <div style="background:#cccccc;padding:0.5em;width:100%;"><span style="color:#fff;font-size:1.2em;">CLIENT LOGIN</span></div>
                 <iframe src="http://www.buildertrend.net/BuilderWebsiteLoginFrame.aspx?builderID=7476" style="border:0px;height:200px;margin-top:1em;width:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
             </div>
        </div>
       <!-- End Login Box -->

Comment: Since I'm not finding "position: absolute;" in my code, I'm guessing that styling is embedded in the link to the main page of coding (at buildertrend.net, linked in the code above)? Which means I wouldn't have access to changing that code. :(

Comment: The property is set in the style.css file. You can also just add a `style="position: relative;"` attribute to the iframe tag.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the iframe tag already has a style attribute, so you'd just add the `position: relative;` to the existing attribute's value. It would be better to change it in the style.css file, though.

Comment: That's awesome — thanks! I didn't add the iFrame for that feature to the stylesheet, (it must be in my stylesheet for the video header on the home page), so I didn't connect that I even had an iFrame tag in my CSS, and it would have taken me forever to figure out that it would affect not just my video heading on the home page, but also every other iFrame (that's correct, right?). So the position: relative will affect all other iFrame coding that I put into my HTML, right?

Comment: You're right. Since the position property was set in the stylesheet, it will apply to all iframe tags in all pages that use that stylesheet. And it would have taken me forever to find the problem, too, if I hadn't used my browser's developer tools. In most browsers, you can access the dev tools by hitting F12. Try it sometime, you won't regret it!

Answer (score 2):

Moving the `<div id="FormLoginPage">` after the iframe seems to do the job with me in the DOM.

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy — thanks for chiming in. In my code, I'm not seeing that div at all, and search can't find anything with "FormLoginPage", but I can see it in your screenshot, so I'm confused why it's not showing in my code on my local side. I'm really new to all this stuff, so I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding. Is it something I should be adding, not moving? Or should it be in my code already and I'm just not seeing it?

Comment: I took another look and it looks like you figured it out. Great job! I assume you're injecting the html somehow, so I can't answer that for sure.

Something else, looking at your console, you currently have the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. That means jQuery isn't getting loaded properly, so you'll need to fix that before you're able to use any jQuery.

Comment: Oh shoot — I don't even know where to start with that one! Ha! That's entirely new to me. I'm trying to learn using a template and building and tweaking from it. I'll try and look up that error and see if there is any information I can get about it and how to fix it. Thanks so much for keeping an eye out for me on that! :)